# LIstView SectionIndexer giving error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, algorithm, listview

I've implemented an `ListView` with `SectionIndexer`. It is working 99% of the times but I found one situation where it is giving error.

The error is:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

And is is happening at this code:

```
    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return indexer.get(sections[section]);
    }
```

Debugging I've found that the above method, for the input I provide at the end of this text, is being called two times. On the second time, when `section`assumes the value `1` it is giving the error.

My adapter is implemented this way:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> implements SectionIndexer {
    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<String[]> foodData;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> indexer;
    private String[] sections;

    public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String[]> allFoodData) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlist, allFoodData);
        this.context = context;
        this.foodData = allFoodData;


        indexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int size = foodData.size();
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            String[] s = foodData.get(x);
            System.out.println("x = " + x + ": foodata[0]=" + s[0] + ": foodata[1]=" + s[1] + ": foodata[2]=" + s[2] + ": foodata[3]=" + s[3]);

            String ch = s[1].substring(0,1);
            ch = ch.toUpperCase();
            if (!indexer.containsKey(ch))
                indexer.put(ch, x);
        }

        Set<String> sectionLetters = indexer.keySet();
        // create a list from the set to sort
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
        Collections.sort(sectionList);
        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
        sections = sectionList.toArray(sections);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    \\\\\\\ stuff
    }

    // ##################### LISTVIEW INDEX #####################
    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return indexer.get(sections[section]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The input is:

```
x = 0: foodata[0]=81: foodata[1]=Iogurte Açucarado batido gordo com cereais e fruta: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 1: foodata[0]=80: foodata[1]=Iogurte Açucarado batido gordo com fruta: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 2: foodata[0]=70: foodata[1]=Iogurte Açucarado batido meio gordo: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 3: foodata[0]=75: foodata[1]=Iogurte Açucarado batido meio gordo com fruta: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 4: foodata[0]=69: foodata[1]=Iogurte Açucarado com edulcorante de síntese, batido magro com cereais: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 5: foodata[0]=68: foodata[1]=Iogurte Açucarado com edulcorante de síntese, sólido magro: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 6: foodata[0]=71: foodata[1]=Iogurte Açucarado líquido meio gordo: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 7: foodata[0]=82: foodata[1]=Iogurte Aromatizado açucarado batido gordo: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 8: foodata[0]=72: foodata[1]=Iogurte Aromatizado açucarado batido meio gordo: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 9: foodata[0]=77: foodata[1]=Iogurte Aromatizado açucarado líquido magro: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 10: foodata[0]=73: foodata[1]=Iogurte Aromatizado açucarado líquido meio gordo: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 11: foodata[0]=78: foodata[1]=Iogurte Aromatizado açucarado sólido magro: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 12: foodata[0]=74: foodata[1]=Iogurte Aromatizado açucarado sólido meio gordo: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 13: foodata[0]=79: foodata[1]=Iogurte Natural sólido magro: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
x = 14: foodata[0]=76: foodata[1]=Iogurte Natural sólido meio gordo: foodata[2]=PT INSA: foodata[3]=1
```

As you can see, the index is only of one letter, in this case `"I"`. I've tried with other inputs that produce only one letter index and this is situation is the only one that gives me error.

Any idea why?

Comment: having same issue, nobody have answer to this ???

Answer (score 3):

This can solve your problem :

```
public int getPositionForSection(int section) {

        if (section > sections.length - 1) {
            return 0;
        } else {

            return alphaIndexer.get(sections[section]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but solved like this: `if (section > sections.length - 1) {
                return sections.length - 1;
            } else {
                return indexer.get(sections[section]);
            }`

Comment: Nice, still logic is same.. :)